# Number of invertible matrix of order 3 using only 0 and 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a 3 × 3 matrix whose each entry is either 0 or 1. If the probability that A is invertible is $\frac{3n}{64}$ , then is equal to_______

My approach is as follow

$A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{a_{11}}}&{{a_{12}}}&{{a_{13}}}\\
{{a_{21}}}&{{a_{22}}}&{{a_{23}}}\\
{{a_{31}}}&{{a_{32}}}&{{a_{33}}}
\end{array}} \right] \Rightarrow \left| A \right| = {a_{11}}\left( {{a_{22}}.{a_{33}} - {a_{23}}.{a_{32}}} \right) - {a_{12}}\left( {{a_{21}}.{a_{33}} - {a_{23}}.{a_{31}}} \right) + {a_{13}}\left( {{a_{21}}.{a_{32}} - {a_{22}}.{a_{31}}} \right)$

The total number of Matrices are $2^9$ and the number of favourable cases is $X$

Hence the probability is $\frac{X}{2^9}$, using $0$ and $1$ how do I find that the matrix is invertible

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I assume that we are looking at matrices over $\mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb R$ if you prefer, makes no difference). This is probably wrong assumption since the answer I get won't be of the form $\frac{3n}{64}$ that is assumed in the question.

I've also added discussion what happens over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.
You can also look at [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices) that Ercanayan provided in the comments of their (at the moment of me writing this) deleted answer for direct formula.

Since I'm still having fun with this, based on the comment by Travis Willse under the same answer I mentioned above, I added the discussion of what happens over $\mathbb Z$ which leads to answer over $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for all $n$.

---

**Let's start over $\mathbb Q$.**

For matrix to be invertible, it has to be of full rank, i.e. its rows need to be linearly independent. So, let's investigate when linear independence can be broken. $\newcommand{\row}[3]{(#1\  #2\  #3)}$

1. There is a zero row $\row 000$.
2. There are two rows that are linearly dependent. Assume none of them is zero row. Then we have $\lambda\row{a_1}{a_2}{a_3} = \row{b_1}{b_2}{b_3}$. At least one $a_i$ is $1$, so we have $\lambda a_i = b_i\implies \lambda = b_i$. Now, $\lambda\neq 0$, so $\lambda = 1$. The conclusion is that two rows are linearly dependent precisely when either one of them is zero or they are equal.
3. One row is linear combination of the two others. Let's assume that all three rows are distinct and non-zero since we'd be back to one of the first two cases. Write $\lambda\row{a_1}{a_2}{a_3}+\mu\row{b_1}{b_2}{b_3} = \row{c_1}{c_2}{c_3}$. Note that since rows $a$ and $b$ are distinct, there is a pair $a_i,b_i$ such that one of them is $1$ and the other is $0$. WLOG, let $a_i = 1$ and $b_i = 0$. This implies $\lambda a_i = c_i$, i.e. $\lambda = c_i$. Now, note that $\lambda \neq 0$, otherwise we'd be back in case 2., which we assumed we are not in. Therefore, $\lambda = 1$ and  $\mu\row{b_1}{b_2}{b_3} = \row{c_1-a_1}{c_2-a_2}{c_3-a_3}$. Note that row on the RHS now has entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$. However, since all $b_j$'s are nonnegative, entries of the row on the RHS are either all nonnegative or all nonpositive, depending on the sign of $\mu$. But, then we have that if $\mu>0$, it must be $\mu = 1$ according to the argument in case 2., and if $\mu < 0$, then $\mu = -1$ according to the same argument if we multiply everything by $-1$. The conclusion is that three distinct, non-zero rows are linearly dependent if and only if one of them is the sum of the other two.

There are $2^3 = 8$ distinct possibilities for each row, $7$ of which are non-zero. According to 1. and 2., for matrix to be invertible, we need to choose it so that all three rows are distinct and non-zero, and we can do it in $7\cdot 6 \cdot 5 = 210$ ways. We need to inspect which of these have a row that's sum of the other two.

Let $\row{a_1}{a_2}{a_3} + \row{b_1}{b_2}{b_3} = \row{c_1}{c_2}{c_3}$. We have $a_i+b_i \in \{0,1\}$, so at most one of $a_i$, $b_i$ is $1$. That means that out of $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3$ we have at most three $1$'s. On the other hand, since both rows $a$ and $b$ are non-zero, we have at least two $1$'s. Therefore, either both $a$ and $b$ have exactly one $1$, or one of them has two $1$'s and the other has one $1$.

If both of them have exactly one $1$, you can choose $a$ in three different ways and $b$ in two different ways to be distinct from $a$, for a total of $6$ different ordered pairs $(a,b)$.

If one of them has two $1$'s, the other is completely determined since it has precisely one $1$ at the place where the other has $0$. If $a$ has two $1$'s, there are $3$ distinct ways to choose $a$ (and therefore $b$ since it's uniquely determined), and by symmetry there are $3$ more ways if $b$ has two $1$'s, for the total of $6$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$.

Therefore, there are total of $12$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that give valid sum $c = a + b$.

Finally, there are $3$ ways to choose which of the rows is the sum of the other two, so out of $210$ matrices that don't break linear independence according to 1. and 2., $3\cdot 12 = 36$ of them break it according to case 3.

We conclude that there are $210 - 36 = 174$ of invertible $3\times 3$ matrices over $\mathbb Q$ with all entries in $\{0,1\}$.

---

**What's different over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?**

If we are looking over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, the cases 1. and 2. are the same, but the conclusion in case 2. is even easier to achieve since $\lambda \in\{0,1\}$.

For the case 3., we don't need to do the case work at all, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are automatically $1$ if want $a,b,c$ to be non-zero and distinct. Furthermore, any choice of distinct, non-zero, $a$ and $b$ will give a valid sum $c = a + b$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Also, $c \neq a,b$ since $a,b$ are non-zero.

Notice that characteristic $2$ gives us that if $c = a +b$, then also $a + c = b$ and $b + c = a$. So, if any row is sum of the other two, all rows are sum of the other two. Which means that all we have to do is pick distinct, non-zero $a,b$, put it as the first and the second row and make the third row $a+b$ and this covers all the cases.

So, the number of invertible $3\times 3$ matrices over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is $7\cdot 6\cdot 5 - 7\cdot 6 = 168$.

---

**Invertible matrices in $M_3(\mathbb Z)$ with entries in $\{0,1\}$.**

The key observation here will be that matrix $A\in M_n(R)$ is invertible if and only if $\det A$ is invertible in $R$.

First, let us observe that $3\times 3$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$ have determinant in $\{0,\pm 1, \pm 2\}$. To see this, let's look at matrix $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
 a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ assume that the first row is non-zero (otherwise the determinant is $0$) and therefore, it's not a loss of generality to assume $a_1 = 1$ (we can switch columns to achieve this, which can only change determinant's sign). Thus,
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
 a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \\
\end{array}\right| = \left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 a_4 & a_5-a_2a_4 & a_6-a_3a_4 \\
 a_7 & a_8-a_2a_7 & a_9-a_3a_7 \\
\end{array}
\right|
= \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_5-a_2a_4 & a_6-a_3a_4 \\
 a_8-a_2a_7 & a_9-a_3a_7 \\
\end{array}
\right|
$$ Notice that the $2\times 2$ determinant has entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$ and since determinant of $2\times 2$ matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$ is $ad-bc$, the above $2\times 2$ determinant is in $\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2\}$, which proves the claim.

From the numbers we got in above sections we can conclude that out of $2^9$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$, there are $334$ with determinant $0$, $168$ with determinant $\pm 1$ and $6$ with determinant $\pm 2$. Notice that $168+6 = 174$, i.e. the matrices with determinant $\pm 2$ are precisely those that are invertible over $\mathbb Q$, but not over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Finally, to answer the question over $\mathbb Z$, the only invertible ones are those with determinants $\pm 1$, and there are $168$ of them. They are the same ones that are invertible over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

As Travis Willse pointed out, we have

$$
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right| = 2
$$ and there are $3! = 6$ matrices obtained by permuting its rows (or columns) which identifies the six "culprits" that are invertible over $\mathbb Q$, but not $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

---

Final comment is that the knowledge of determinants also answers the question over any $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, there are $174$ invertible matrices for $n$ odd and $168$ for $n$ even since it boils down to the question whether $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ or not.

Comment: @Ercanayan, reading the question more carefully, it seems that your answer is the correct one because $174/2^9$ is not of the form $3n/64$ for integer $n$, while $168/2^9$ is.

Comment: @Travis Willse I added your remarks from comments in my answer, hopefully you don't mind.

Comment: wow i did not expect this problem to have these many layers, thank you for introducing me to this. I had answered in a very non-rigorous manner.

Comment: @Ercanayan, well I wanted to solve the problem over $\mathbb Q$ since it seemed to be the harder case, then since you deleted your answer I thought why not modify what I have for that case as well as it was easy to do and then Travis' comment made me think about $\mathbb Z$ as well, so I ended up solving it for all unital commutative rings by chance.

Answer (score 1):

Hints

Can there be a zero column (or row) for the matrix to be invertible?

Can the columns (or rows) be linearly dependent?